# how to (count all record)/2 in Crystal Report?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

how to (count all record)/2  and show the result in the report - in Crystal Report ?

(working in C#)

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to display half the record count in the report somewhere?

Just create a formula field with the text :

```
RecordNumber/2
```

and place it in the report footer.

Comment: Thank's for the help
but, how i create formula field ?

Comment: Open the Field Explorer/Data Explorer, click Formula Fields, then the New button.